# How can I check json data before summing if it's a positive integer in Javascrict

Tags: javascript

I received a JSON record. The data set can vary depending on the order of the data. I need individual data because they will be used later for another function. (weight, apples, bananas)
I'm supposed to check this for errors and log the errors in an array. Each error should be on its own line from the array in console.log.

I can't do that. I can output that in an extra line with .join ('\ n') but then I no longer have an array.

The second problem is that I can't manage apples and bananas before adding them to check whether they are whole fruits. I can only do it afterwards. But 1.5 + 1.5 would then be 3. This is true for me, but I checked it incorrectly.
Sorry for the whole console.log. I just need to understand the individual steps.

How can I log the errors individually per line as an array?

And how can I check the fruits beforehand to see if the data are only whole positive numbers?

```js
'use strict';

// data to check
const receivedData = {
  age: 'twenty', //only numbers
  fruits: [{
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 5
    },
    {
      type: 'apple',
      amount: 1.5
    }, //only whole fruits .5 is not allowed
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 2
    },
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 1.5
    },
    {
      type: 'apple',
      amount: 2
    },
  ],
};

//check age
const age = 'age';
const weightData = receivedData[age];
console.log(weightData);
const validateWeight = Math.sign(weightData); //1 = true
//console.log(validateWeight); //Test Log

//check fruits
const fruits = 'fruits';
const fruitsData = receivedData[fruits];
//console.log(fruitsData); //Test Log

const resultFruits = fruitsData.reduce(
  (a, {
    type,
    amount
  }) => ((a[type] = (a[type] || 0) + amount), a), {}
);

//console.log(resultFruits); //Test Log

const banana = 'banana';
const resultBanana = resultFruits[banana];
console.log(resultBanana);

const apple = 'apple';
const resultApple = resultFruits[apple];
console.log(resultApple);

//console.log(typeof resultBanana); //Test Log
const validateApple = resultApple - Math.floor(resultApple); //0 = true
const validateBanana = resultBanana - Math.floor(resultBanana);
//console.log(validateApple) //Test Log

const validateDataWeight = validateWeight === 1 ? '' : `${weightData} is not a number`;
const validateDataApple =
  validateApple === 0 ? '' : `${resultApple} is not a valid number of apples`;

const validateDataBanana =
  validateBanana === 0 ? '' : `${resultBanana} is not a valid number of bananas`;

const validateData = [validateDataWeight, validateDataApple, validateDataBanana];

console.log(validateData.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array `arr_error`  then check data and add errors to the array.

```
arr_error = [];
// data to check
const d = {
  age: 'twenty', //only numbers
  fruits: [{
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 5
    },
    {
      type: 'apple',
      amount: 1.5
    }, //only whole fruits .5 is not allowed
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 2
    },
    {
      type: 'banana',
      amount: 1.5
    },
    {
      type: 'apple',
      amount: 2
    },
  ],
};

for (const k in d){     
    if (k == "age" && ! Number.isInteger(d[k]) ){
       arr_error.push({"age": " not integer "});
    }
    if (k == "fruits"){    
      for (i=0;i<d[k].length;i++){
         hf = d[k][i];                  
         if ( ! Number.isInteger(hf["amount"]) ){
            arr_error.push(
              {"fruits_id":i, "err": "amount not int" }
            );
         }     
    
         //ckeck if is positive ,  number  > 0 
    
         if ( ! hf["amount"] > 0 ){
            arr_error.push(
              {"fruits_id":i, "err": "amount not positive" }
            );
         }        
    
      }
    }
}   
    
console.log(arr_error);
```

output:

```
[
{age: " not integer "},
{fruits_id: 1 ,err: "amount not int"},
{fruits_id: 3 ,err: "amount not int"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I haven't worked with `for` yet. I should take ES6 without `for`.